# Replace whole or partial string

Tags: c#, replace

in C# I would use Replace in strings that match a whole string or also a single part of the string:

My pattern `example string`

My strings

```
This is the first example string
This is the second example
```

What I want to get

```
This is the first
This is the second
```

If I use `.Replace(pattern, string)` I achieve only the first result, not the second.

Please someone can help me?

Here a more exhaustive example:

```
Golf 7ª serie
GOLF 1.6 TDI TREND

Golf 7ª serie
Golf 1.6 TDI 90 CV 5p. Business Trendline BlueMotion Tech.

Freelander 2ª serie
Freelander 2.2 TD4 S.W. XS

Juke
Juke 1.5 dCi Start&Stop Acenta
```

As you can see, in the first 3 examples, th pattern is partially matched in the string, while in the 4th example it matches completely the string.
I want to obtain:

```
1.6 TDI TREND
1.6 TDI 90 CV 5p. Business Trendline BlueMotion Tech.
2.2 TD4 S.W. XS
1.5 dCi Start&Stop Acenta
```

So any word contained in the first string must be deleted from the second

Comment: What is there in the pattern?

Comment: please show your code to better illustrate your description.

Comment: Wouldn't the first result then be "Th h f" (as "e", "s", "i" and "t" also match part of "example string"). Or do you only want to replace whole words?

Comment: But you need to replace the word "string" only if is it after the word "example" or do you want to replace both strings regardless where they are?

Comment: Why not replace each of your pattern words independently. replace 'example' and then replace 'string'? You can also use regular expressions for this purpose

Comment: maybe `string substring= yourstring.Substring(0, one.IndexOf("example"));`

Comment: @Klaus: I want to replace wholw words

Comment: your teacher did not tell you how `Replace()` works? you have few solutions, but replace method can be used multiple times on single string. just add another `Raplace()` as follows: `yor_sentence.Replace("example", "").Replace("string", "");`.

Comment: @Alfra it seems you want every thing befor "example"??

Comment: Are you concerned about keeping extra spaces in your string? (replacing words in your first example would lead to `This is the first  ` - with 2 spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over each word in the pattern and replace them one by one

```
var val = "This is the first example string";
var pattern = "example string";

foreach(var removeWord in pattern.Split(null))
{
    val = val.Replace(removeWord, string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following should remove both 'example' and 'string' from the starting string.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var result = Regex.Replace("This is the first example string", "(example|string)?", "" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is a generic solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fs = "This is the first example string";
    var ss = "This is the second example";
    var patternString = "example string";

    var patterns = patternString.Split(" ");

    foreach (string pattern in patterns)
    {
        fs = fs.Replace(pattern, "");
        ss = ss.Replace(pattern, "");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything before example the simplest way is :

```
string substring = yourstring.Substring(0, one.IndexOf("example"));
```

The regex example is also available:

```
Match result = Regex.Match("yourstring", @"^.*?(?=example)");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to do this would avoid if possible `string.Replace`.

When dealing with tasks that involve *contains* questions, using sets is usually the best option:

```
var patternWords = 
    new HashSet<string>(
        pattern.Split(
           new[] { ‘ ‘ },
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

var words = str.Split(
    new[] { ‘ ‘ },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var matches = words.Where(
    w => !patternWords.Contains(w));
var newStr = string.Join(
    “ “, matches);
```